# Radio Button set custom drawable not working

Tags: android, radio-button

I have used the radio button and set a custom drawable for a check/uncheck

I want to this

[image]

but my current output is this

[image]

Radio button XML code

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/segmented2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/colorRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/color_color" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/gradientRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/color_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

style/RadioButton

```
<style name="RadioButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">   
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/radio_checked_unchecked</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">70dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">35dp</item>    
    </style>
```

drawable/radio_checked_unchecked.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: set button to `@null` and set the radioGroup background to the custom drawable

Comment: @MAshhal thanks you for the answer but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an idea from the given answer and I found a solution to my question

**Change**

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/colorRadioButton"
        style="@style/RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/color_color" />
```

**To**

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/autoRadioButton"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@string/auto"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/radio_checked_unchecked"/>
```

set `android:drawableStart` to set custom drawable and set `button="@null"`

**style**

```
<style name="RadioButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/bvc_sticker_button_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:button">@null</item> 
        <item name="android:minWidth">70dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">35dp</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_medium</item>
    </style>
```

use the above code and get output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_checked_unchecked</item>
<item name="android:button">@null</item>
```

instead of this:

```
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
<item name="android:button">@drawable/radio_checked_unchecked</item>
```

in your style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not working

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to change the **android:orientation** from **horizontal** to **vertical**. You can also use fixed layout width and height if you use larger or unscalable custom drawables.

So, your updated RadioGroup codebase will be like below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/segmented2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/colorRadioButton"
        style="@style/RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/color_color" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/gradientRadioButton"
        style="@style/RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/color_gradient"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RadioGroup>
```

**Also, button should be set to @null, and the radioGroup background should be your custom drawable.**

So, your updated style codebase will be like below:

```
<style name="RadioButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_checked_unchecked</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">70dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">35dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not working